# awk change shell variable

Tags: unix, awk

I would like to modify several shell variables within awk:
`echo "$LINE_IN" | awk '/pattern1/ {print $0; WRITTEN=1; REC=$REC+1}' >> $FILE1`

I tried to put eval, but still does not work:

`eval $( echo "$LINE_IN" | awk '/pattern1/ {print $0; WRITTEN=1; REC=$REC+1}' >> $FILE1 )`

Any suggestion?
I would like to use k-shell script, thanks!

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: `WRITTEN=1; REC=$REC+1` why do you need to do this in `awk`?

Comment: Please explain your requirments. Maybe something like REC=$(grep -Ec 'pattern1' <<< "${LINE_IN}")`

Comment: I am reading a file line by line (in a loop), if the line contains pattern1 then I will write it out to $FILE1. WRITTEN=1 lets me know that a line contains pattern1 has been written out. If all the lines read do not contain the pattern1, then WRITTEN will not be set to 1 (it was set to 0 before this read loop), the REC=$REC+1 is to know how many lines contain pattern1 have been written out.

Answer (score 0):

Count the hits when you are finished:

```
echo "${LINE_IN}" | grep -E 'pattern1' > "${FILE1}"
REC=$(wc -l < "${FILE1}")
if (( REC > 0 )); then 
   WRITTEN=1
fi
```

When you really want to use `awk`, you must let awk write the results to stdout and parse stdout:

```
echo "${LINE_IN}" | awk '/echo/ {print $0 > "x3"; WRITTEN=1; REC++}
                         END { print "WRITTEN=" WRITTEN; print "REC=" REC}'
WRITTEN=1
REC=6
```

And when you want the variables really set, wrap it:

```
source (echo "${LINE_IN}" | awk '/echo/ {print $0 > "x3"; WRITTEN=1; REC++}
                         END { print "WRITTEN=" WRITTEN; print "REC=" REC}')
```

Note: Get used to using lowercase variable names like `written`, `file` and `rec`.